# Cannot write a question with the word 'question' in the title

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, title, quality-filter

I can't "save edits" to the following question: [Open Source Question Answering Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527059/open-source-question-answering-frameworks) , because it has the word 'Question' in the title.

I understand the rationale behind not allowing this word in the title, but it is still wrong.

Comment: You could use QA instead.

Comment: Can you save the edit with the title being "Open Source Question-Answering Frameworks"?

Comment: @AndersUP, no I can't.

Comment: But, how did it get placed originally?! How is that possible?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil it was likely posted before the filter was put in place.  (Or before that word was added to the filter.)

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil, 'Q&A' and 'QA' both have different meanings from 'question answering'.

Comment: If you understand the rationale, and you understand that it is done on purpose, then you should understand that it is not a bug.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, let's not argue :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/thats-not-a-bug-its-a-feature-request.html